# Node.JS: Assert authorized before sending data over HTTPS

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, client

I understand I need to check the `response.connection.authorized` field to see if the SSL/TLS connection is secure and to the correct server.

However, without sending a request, I cannot get the response to begin with. How can I verify a secure connection *before* sending the request data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days, I am assuming it can't be done without modification to the `https` component itself. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I posted [an issue report on this](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2247).